# Why was this question put on hold as “too broad”?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, needs-more-focus

Two days ago I saw this question and was baffled that it was put on hold as "too broad": [Unable to import .p12 keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649176/unable-to-import-p12-keystore)

In fact the question is rather specific and none of the criteria for "too broad" apply:

- Because of the provided error message there is exactly one valid answer.
- Two short sentences are enough to explain the cause of the error message and to provide a solution to the problem (see comments).

The question was never edited, so it is not possible that it is an improved version of the original "too broad" question.

Am I missing something or why were five users convinced that this question should be closed?

**Update:**

The question was put on hold again, this time for being off-topic:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers.

This is getting ridiculous. The question includes a specific error message "EC KeyFactory not available" and the command that produced it.

If someone else encounters the same error message, he will google for it and find this question on SO with a solution. That is how it should be, right?

Comment: I don't know the technologies so I can speak specifically but "Too Broad" is often used when the question lacks a complete problem statement or is missing key details because an answer to cover all of the possible options would be too long for this format.

Comment: Yes, that is how I understand "too broad" too, but in this case the question neither lacks a complete problem statement nor is it missing key details. Basically it is a simple "I tried to do that with this command and got this error". And the error message is so specific that it allows only one answer.

Comment: The best you can do is get it reopened, and unfortunately given your rep level, you don't really have an option since you can't vote to reopen it.  If there is something you see that is missing or unclear, you might try to edit it to clear it up, which should throw it into the review queue (assuming the edit gets approved).

Comment: I don't think I would have voted for too broad - however, keep in mind, even if the content is perfect, knowing how to format the question is very important. Try formatting the code and the quote next time.

Comment: @Alex: Not my question, I just stumbled over it and wondered what went wrong here. But you brought up a good point, the formatting is really not very well done. I just hope that this was not the reason for closing the question.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it was "Any suggestions?" that got this one closed.  "How do I resolve this error so I can import this key?" would have been much better.  The general formatting, while not itself a close reason, might get readers in the mindset of a low-quality question.  (I edited, but I can't vote to reopen.)

Comment: Ask the reviewers: Triage: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6577942 , Close: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6578187 , Reopen: http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/6597151 . Seems to be a consensus to close it among all of them.

Comment: How do I ask the reviewers? I can see the consensus in your links but still no reason.

Comment: @Omikron: I was the one leaving it closed for reasons as, 1) `I created a .p12 keystore using openssl from a pkcs8 keystore`-> How exactly? 2) What versions have you used 3) What are those input files? 4) What have you read about the error output on Google? 5) What have you learnt? 6) What did you try to resolve it? 7) etc. There is too much information missing. While I would have opted for a different close reason, this is not a reason to reopen.

Comment: I would add that **none** of the close voters have significant reputation in Java tag.

Comment: @lpapp and you left none of that as comment in the question in question. Just close it and move on, eh? No wonder SO lately isn't considered newbie friendly...

Comment: @K.L.: first of all, if you reread it, but carefully this time, you can notice that I did **not** close it. Secondly, why is it good to replicate the link content mentioned in the close reason for the OP? To generate unfruitful discussions like this here where I am honestly trying to speak up to give some feedback to be fair alone from the crowd? I feel unappreciated and you encourage me to skip it next time.

Comment: @lpapp "Just close and move on" refered to the general attitude as perceived by me, not implying to you closing the question. But you will have to rephrase the latter bit, cause i cant understand what is it trying to say. And as far as I know, the question was just closed as "too broad" with no explanation why exactly is it too broad for the person who asked that question. If such explanation was there, Omikron would not have started this on meta. in my prev. comment I pointed out that you were willing to explain why you voted for leaving the question closed here but not at the q itself.

Comment: To put it simply - it would be better to leave the exact same comment on the question itself and not the meta discussion so that both the person asking and future visitors would know what the qeustion lacked and why it was closed.

Comment: No, closures always come with reasoning automatically. You need to spend more time on seeing closed questions. `There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question or leave a comment.`

Comment: @lpapp the autogiven reason explains nothing. If Omikron had the impression that the question lacks no detail, then maybe a lot of people would get the same impression. I wasnt hostile towards you in my first comment, byt towards the no-commenting trend. I said you should leave those reasons in the question not here, and that no comments from reviewers/closers are bad. No need to be defensive or retaliate on me with ad hominem arguments - you should spend less time on making ad hominem arguments (see what I did there?).

Comment: The explanation has links embedded, including the help center, OK, I am out. I will not try to help next time. It turns out bad when one tries to help, so it is not worth it. I would not wonder if others had come to the same conclusion a while ago.

Comment: @lpapp: Thank you very much for contributing to this discussion as one of the reviewers! However, I disagree with most of the arguments you have listed. 1) is not necessary because it was a previous step and has nothing to do with the problem 2) yes, that would have been nice 3) wrong question 4) there is only one relevant google result and it does not answer the question, btw. another reason to re-open the question 5) is this seriously necessary in every question? 6) there was not much he could have tried 7) obviously there was enough information to correctly answer the question

Comment: Why do you ask if you argue? This is my reasoning. My standards are high. Your standards may be much lower and I do not completely mind in this case since java is a looser language anyway... ;-) It does not matter to me whether you disagree; those are still my points to check to keep this site high-quality and perhaps other people's, too. If there is no effort put into the question, not even google readups what he actually read about the error message, let alone what he has tried. Such questions are not worth our time.

Comment: As for the points: 1) How do you know for _sure_ it has nothing to do with it? I do not, so I need it. I am not a clairvoyant with a crystall ball. I want to provide the best answer. 3) Wrong question to ask for the input, eh? 4) So where is the explanation about the google result then?? 5) Yes, it is very seriously necessary. 6) OK, so "gimme the solution without effort"... Downvote and close vote those. 7) Apparently, There was not for many people including me. -- You can argue this all, but people disagreed with you. Just accept that there are different people and move on.

Comment: I won't say this is the case with lpapp but time and time again I see people closing question because they don't understand them.  I don't know much about this topic but in other cases I which I do have a deep know of I've seem people close questions as "not clear" or "to broad" when in fact they just did not understand the question.

Comment: The speed of the close process worries me a lot. It's getting out of control.

Comment: @lpapp You *voted to close*, and we can all see this.

Comment: @cybermonkey actually he voted to leave it closed (in the reopen queue), which isn't quite the same as **to** close.

Comment: There seems to be a running battle between moderators here; the question has been closed/reopened at least three times today, most likely by different moderators. Can't moderators just agree to close/keep the post open permanently and stop messing about with it?

Comment: @lpapp Your stated reasons do not hold water for a moment. (1) There is only one way to do that with OpenSSL; (2) is not necessarIly relevant and could have been requested via a comment; (3) they are explicitly stated to be PKCS#8 files; (4) and (5) aren't really distinct; (6) doesn't necessarily make sense; (7) etc such as what? It is a perfectly clear question to me and it almost certainly has a single correct answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

My 2 cents.

I've noticed how sometimes when closing questions an *avalanche effect* takes place starting with a tiny rock.

If you see the [original unedited question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27649176/revisions) in **my opinion** that tiny rock was the fact that the question was missing a ***This is what I tried***. This is what any programmer regardless of technology can ascertain.

.....Furthermore the bad formatting (things as tiny as highlighting the error message, capitalizing i's etc fueled that avalanche, as you'll see how in [the review triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6577942), 1 of 4 thought it was **Unsalvageable** and the other 3 thought it **Should be Improved**)

It feels hard to make close/reopen/delete/undelete votes on questions, once you have the power to do so. There won't ever be complete consensus and we can't make everybody happy.

An example: In **my opinion** yet again, as opposed to *@Ipapp*, I feel the question may be reopened because you gave the OP an answer that may be useful to many out on the internet that might have come across this or a similar problem. Therefore I vote to reopen.

Comment: related: [Bandwagon effect in close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144557/165773) at MSE

Comment: i'm with you gideon, also having, at this moment, +17 for the question and +22 for the answer might be because of this meta post or maybe not. But it seem weird to have it closed now.

Answer (score -5):

Because people abuse their power here on Stack Overflow. Simply put, the user was probably being shunned for being new to the site.

Comment: `Because people abuse their power here on Stack Overflow`; care to give an example? If you think you witness a moderator/any user abusing their privileges, simply *flag* with a custom flag with your suspicions. If that fails you can always come to Meta.

Comment: I think this too. It's not a case of individuals abusing power, but more a case of social mimicking. One person marks something in a negative way, and that encourages group-think. It's a very well known social phenomenon.

Answer (score -18):

This question still lacks critical information to narrow it to the point of being answered: to start with, it nowhere states what version of Java you are using.

Comment: The OP isn't the author of the question, you should edit your answer. If you're nitpicking at small things such as the Java version, there wouldn't be many good questions left on SO.

Comment: Also, this would be a perfect comment on the question, but no one of the people who voted for closing the question left it there. When I read the question, I saw it as a reasonable one, even tho im no expert in that field. So If an expert wants/needs more details, it would be optimal to ask for them instead of just voting to close.

Comment: As a side note, if all questions would specify everything to the evry last bit, they would be all too localized, and SO would be a free tech support site, not a knowledge base.

Comment: Although stating the Java version in questions seems a good idea in general, it is certainly not "critical information" in this case: Only Java 6 could have produced that specific error message. And i doubt that someone who does not understand the error message, would have been able to answer the question anyway. In addition, the command that caused the error message contains a parameter that was not available before Java 6.

Comment: @K.L. again my 2c. Many times I've put up a comment asking more information when the question is within my tech area. However, the OP doesn't respond. Then what are we to do? .I always tell my colleagues and do this myself, when posting on SO you **need to keep an eye on your question.** People ask for clarifications etc and sometimes that itself answers your question. Given the fact that we get  **5700 questions per day** if the OP is uninterested in giving more info, voting to close and prevent garbage accumulating is what the community mods lean towards.

Comment: @gideon If the OP does not respond, you are doing us all a favour closing the question, indeed! Thank you for your work! Sadly, many people dont leave the comment asking for additional details like you do, and that's what i had in mind with my comment :)

Comment: @K.L. True, but however if you attempt to flag your own question it'll tell you what other users have flagged the question for. Not as useful as a comment explaining specifically *why*  it was flagged/closed, but is useful in determining the rough reason.