# Are answers that include Computer Science terms & concepts looked down upon here?

Tags: discussion, answers

I've noticed that when I explain an answer to a question along with code, and a description of the problem that was causing it while using Computer Science terms and concepts, my answers will get down-voted, although my answer does, in fact, solve the problem.

For instance, my last answer I went into a brief description about allocating memory to the heap vs stack memory and it was down-voted 2 times.

Should I refrain from using "Computer Science" terms. I don't want to say jargon because it is not jargon.

Comment: Pretty sure that's **not** why you were downvoted though I can't say why since I didn't dv. Also, you had 3 upvotes. I wouldn't worry about 2 downvotes on one question. But, to answer your question, no you shouldn't refrain from using technical,relevant terms/jargon/words

Comment: You are posting buggy code, forgetting the string terminator is a pretty big boo-boo.

Comment: Without a link to the answer concerned it's all a bit vague, but you seem to be jumping to conclusions here, [and elsewhere](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281461/207421), and [here too](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278514/mods-deleting-comments-because-they-dont-agree). Try to resist the temptation. OTOH I got downvoted for citing Knuth, so anything can happen.

Comment: @EJP You're creeping on my past to accomplish what exactly?.

Comment: To comment on your question. The original purpose was to find the answer you're complaining about here, because you didn't provide a link, but the other things jumped out. Within five minutes too, no major effort required.

Answer (score 12):

I doubt that you were downvoted for the terminology. I think it's desirable to use precise terms. If somebody doesn't know them, they can look them up, and learn something on the way. Of course you should not go overboard and make explanations much more complicated than they should be. But a term like "heap memory" is very commonly used, and should be familiar to anybody using a programming language like C.

As always, only the people who downvoted know why they did. Some possibilities, without having any more insight (I did not vote):

- A couple of people left comments suggesting that they don't like the way you copied the string.
- There is no need to use dynamic memory allocation in this case. The accepted answer puts the struct on the stack, which is simpler and perfectly appropriate in this case.
- This is nitpicking, but I don't think your terminology is entirely precise. You say that "you need to allocate memory for that pointer". The memory allocation that is needed is not for the pointer, it is for the struct that the pointer points to. The pointer itself is on the stack.

Comment: Point 2: He was looking like he was planning on using a pointer for his struct, so that is why I suggested the code that I did.